# How to get the line number from a Stack Trace?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception, stack-trace, windows-phone

I am trying to get the line number from a stack trace in my WP7 app. I have set debug info to full and am running the app in the Debug configuration, but there are no line numbers in stack traces. How can I fix this? I am aware of BugSense, but do not want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think this is even possible, as `line  number` refers to the number of the line inside *code-file*, which has lost any relation with the binary after compilation. That's why we use `PDB` files. *They* are "databases" for holding the relation between actually executed code and the final binary state of it.

So don't think there would be any possibility to get a `line number` at **runtime**.

But if you have a `PDB` file of last compilation, you can potentially get that information from

[StackFrame.GetFileLineNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilelinenumber.aspx) , which does:

> Gets the line number in the file that contains the code that is
>   executing. This information is typically extracted from the debugging
>   symbols for the executable.